# Implementing AppenderSkeleton in Orchard

Tags: c#, log4net, orchardcms, sentry

## Main question:

I want to log errors and message from **Orchard** to **Sentry**.
In order to do this I have created a `SentryAppender` implementing `AppenderSkeleton` from **log4net**.
When logging a message in Orchard it's possible to pass a format followed by arguments, ex:
`logger.Info("My value is: {0}", 1337)`
When receiving a `LoggingEvent` in the `Append` method, the event will contain a `MessageObject`. This object will contain `m_format` and `m_args` which contain the format and arguments that where originally provided when calling the logger.
These properties are however inaccessible, as they are private and are being placed on a sealed class at runtime.
I can call `RenderLoggingEvent` to get the rendered message, however if I pass this to **Sentry** it will not be able to properly group the messages, there will be a new log event for each different parameter.

**Question:**
Is there a way to access the format and args, or should I be implementing a different base class?

---

### Additional issue:

I am not sure if this merits it's own question.
The `LoggingEvent` will sometimes have `LocationInformation` on it, with information on what method was called and where from. However this information will always look as if the call to the logger came from within the `CastleLogger`.

Is there a way to ensure this information points back to the real origin of the call to the logger?